# Computing Training Set Perplexity of a Neural Language Model: Too low values

Tags: neural-networks, language-models, cross-entropy

I am implementing a Language Model based on a Deep Learning architecture (RNN+Softmax).

The cost function I am using is the cross-entropy between the vector of probabilities at the softmax layer and the one-hot vector of the target word to predict.

For every epoch, I am computing the perplexity as:
[image: Perplexity of a Language Model per-epoch] 
where [image: Batches-per_epoch] is the number of batches per-epoch.

Knowing that [image: Perplexity-Cross-Entropy]

The problem here that after a given number of epochs the total cross-entropy per-epoch starts dropping and dividing it by the number of batches per-epoch will lead to very low perplexity values with respect to state of the art perplexity values on the same Corpus I am using in my experiments.

Am I computing the training set perplexity in a wrong way ?

Any kind of help is hugely appreciated.

Comment: how do you compute the total cross-entropy per-epoch?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt total cross-entropy per-epoch is the exponent of the first formula I gave above where N is the number of batches per-epoch and cross-entropy_i is the average of cross-entropi(es) obtained at each iteration of a batch.

Comment: I see. Just wanted to make sure you don't divide more than necessary. I put the perplexity  equations here, you may want to double check: [Comparing Perplexities With Different Data Set Sizes](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/242620/12359)

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Thank you for your fast reply. So according to equations you pointed me to, you are suggesting that it is better to compute, for each epoch, the Average cross-entropy for each word (when this word is the target) and then dividing the sum of all the Average cross-entropies on the number of words constituting the vocabulary. Am I getting this right ?